# Visual studio 2022 razor and css editor: documentation reference

Tags: css, visual-studio, razor, blazor, editor

I've created a Blazor Web assembly project in Visual Studio 2022. I noticed that the Context Help (F1) is not navigating to the reference documentation in either razor or css file. The same is working in visual studio code. Not sure if I am missing any settings. Could you please help with resolving this issue?

Comment: What's your VS version? 2022 is still in preview and has updates like once a week, Blazor integration is better now but not perfect actually :/

Comment: It is the latest Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.6